# With Primefaces fileUpload component, is there an event fired when the user clicks "Cancel"?

Tags: java, jsf, upload, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.0.RC1 and on a form I have a `<p:fileUpload mode="advanced" auto="true">` component. This has a fileUploadListener that is writing a copy of the temp file to disk.

The issue is (when uploading a file everything runs fine) that if while the file is being written to disk the user clicks the "Cancel" button, the file may already be partially written to the disk, but I need to be able to delete it at that point. Is there an event fired when the user clicks cancel?

**EDIT:** To clarify, the cancel button is still visible (and clickable) while the file upload event handler is executing. The issue is only if the user clicks cancel at this point. Clicking cancel while the file is still being uploaded to the server is fine.

Comment: but the fileUploadListener is being called only upon the end of file uploaded from the user , and right before you actually able to save it to DB or FileSystem, so if the user will click the Cancel button you wont get to the fileUploadListener at all...

Comment: Primefaces displays the cancel button until after the fileUploadListener returns. So while I am writing the file to the disk (after file is uploaded), the cancel button is clickable. When it is clicked, writing the file continues until it is complete, but I need to know if the cancel button was clicked in that time so I can remove the file.

Comment: Two things: Have you asked on the Primefaces forum and why aren't you on the current release of Primefaces? RC1 has all sorts of issues :)

Comment: Unfortunately, we are nearing the end of development on the site, and people don't want to upgrade to the newer release until later because this is the only issue we are having with PrimeFaces. I haven't asked on the PF forum yet though, I will do that.

Comment: @htrk123: Bad idea. By developing against an old, unstable and incomplete version, you are accruing technical debt that will bite you in the butt very quickly. Don't ignore this advice all the while expecting sympathy and help.

Comment: @SteveTaylor I know, unfortunately it is out of my hands as the project lead has decided not to update

Comment: @htrk123: The project lead sounds like an idiot. Go above him/her or leave the project. When the project lead's supervisor discovers that the project lead is building upon an unstable foundation - which will no doubt blow out the budget and schedule - I'm sure he/she won't be happy about it at all. You could start by bringing up the topic with the project lead and mentioning that you want to get a second opinion. The threat alone should be enough, but be prepared to act if it is not. Your job is probably more secure than you may think. Skype chat me on tayl0270 if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to set up a dedicated temporary directory to receive file uploaded thanks to the `uploadDirectory` parameter of `FileUploadFilter` in your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
  </filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>/var/tmp/primefaces-upload</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

I guess your code already move fully uploaded files to its definite location.

I propose you configure a regular job (with Quartz for instance) to remove any file older than more than one hour (or a configurable timeout) from the upload directory.

Comment: Thanks @YvesMartin, I suppose this will have to do until we can move to the newest stable Primefaces release next month